# count + merge same values in different columns

Tags: sql

I have a select which give me following output:

[image]

Now I want to merge the entrys where for a name like 'Jacobson' the number and year is the same and Count these same entrys.

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is a so called `group by` operation.

```
Select Number, Name, Year, Count(*)
From table
Group By Number, Name, Year
```

Entries with the same Number, Name and Year are grouped and counted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *extract* the `year` from date and add it in `Group By`

```
Select Name,Year(datecol), Count(1)
From Yourtable
Group By Name,Year(datecol)
```

Most of the database engine supports `YEAR` function. If no then add the DBMS you are using